# Rendering speed is very slow when i use offline map data in osmdroid MapView

Tags: android, osmdroid

My offline map data source format is MBTiles . The database got 2 tables:
Table1 name is preferences which stored the data like: 
name,value

Table2 name is tiles which store the data like:

tileKey,zoom,row,col,image

Then i create a class

public class MBTileSource extends BitmapTileSourceBase {

```
// Log log log log ...
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(MBTileSource.class);

// Database related fields
public final static String TABLE_TILES = "tiles";
public final static String COL_TILES_ZOOM_LEVEL = "zoom";
public final static String COL_TILES_TILE_COLUMN = "col";
public final static String COL_TILES_TILE_ROW = "row";
public final static String COL_TILES_TILE_DATA = "image";

protected SQLiteDatabase database;
protected File archive;

// Reasonable defaults ..
public static final int minZoom = 8;
public static final int maxZoom = 15;
public static final int tileSizePixels = 256;

// Required for the superclass
public static final string resourceId = ResourceProxy.string.offline_mode;

/**
 * The reason this constructor is protected is because all parameters,
 * except file should be determined from the archive file. Therefore a
 * factory method is necessary.
 * 
 * @param minZoom
 * @param maxZoom
 * @param tileSizePixels
 * @param file
 */
protected MBTileSource(int minZoom, int maxZoom, int tileSizePixels,
        File file, SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super("sqlite", resourceId, minZoom, maxZoom, tileSizePixels, ".png");

    archive = file;
    database = db;
}

/**
 * Creates a new MBTileSource from file.
 * 
 * Parameters minZoom, maxZoom en tileSizePixels are obtained from the
 * database. If they cannot be obtained from the DB, the default values as
 * defined by this class are used.
 * 
 * @param file
 * @return
 */
public static MBTileSource createFromFile(File file) {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    int flags = SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS
            | SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY;

    // int value;
    int minZoomLevel=minZoom;
    int maxZoomLevel=maxZoom;
    int tileSize = tileSizePixels;
    InputStream is = null;

    // Open the database
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(file.getAbsolutePath(), null, flags);

    // Get the minimum zoomlevel from the MBTiles file
    Cursor pCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM preferences;", null);
    try {
        if (pCursor.getCount() != 0) {
            pCursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                String name=pCursor.getString(pCursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("map.minZoom")){
                    minZoomLevel=pCursor.getInt(pCursor.getColumnIndex("value"));
                }else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("map.maxZoom")){
                    maxZoomLevel=pCursor.getInt(pCursor.getColumnIndex("value"));
                }else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("map.tileSideLength")){
                    tileSize=pCursor.getInt(pCursor.getColumnIndex("value"));
                }
            } while (pCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        pCursor.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    return new MBTileSource(minZoomLevel, maxZoomLevel, tileSize, file, db);
}

public InputStream getInputStream(MapTile pTile) {

    try {
        InputStream ret = null;
        final String[] tile = { COL_TILES_TILE_DATA };
        final String[] xyz = {
                Integer.toString(pTile.getX()),
                Double.toString(Math.pow(2, pTile.getZoomLevel())
                        - pTile.getY() - 1),
                Integer.toString(pTile.getZoomLevel()) };

        final Cursor cur = database.query(TABLE_TILES, tile,
                "col=? and row=? and zoom=?", xyz, null,
                null, null);

        if (cur.getCount() != 0) {
            cur.moveToFirst();
            ret = new ByteArrayInputStream(cur.getBlob(0));
        }

        cur.close();

        if (ret != null) {
            return ret;
        }

    } catch (final Throwable e) {
        logger.warn("Error getting db stream: " + pTile, e);
    }

    return null;

}
```

}

it work well to show the off line map. Only one problem is : The rendering speed is really slow

any suggestion?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to extend `BitmapTileSourceBase`. You want to create a tile provider chain that includes a `MapTileFileArchiveProvider` and your own `IArchiveFile`. See [DatabaseFileArchive.java](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/modules/DatabaseFileArchive.java) for an example of a database backed `IArchiveFile`.

If you still have speed issues you should run the profiler to see where the slow down is.

Answer (score 0):

do you have any indexes on your mbtiles file?   Kurtzmarc's answer will work, but its a mess going that route.   I've got it working and performance is ok, but I want a cleaner solution.   I was thinking of starting from the XYTileSource and moving on from there.